# C++ Using naked, instead of smart pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        vec.push_back("adsf");
    }
    std::string* myPoint = &vec[1];
    *myPoint = "this works";
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> str_ptr = std::make_shared<std::string>(vec[0]);
    str_ptr->push_back('this does not push_back to the end of the string stored in at vec[0]');
    for(int i =0;i<10;i++){
        std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl; //does not print the new value set by str_ptr
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I want here is to update a value in `vec` through a pointer. As I've understood smart pointers are no good for this task. Is using a naked pointer here, an acceptable alternative?

Comment: `str_ptr->push_back()` won't compile

Comment: How about `vec[0].push_back()`?

Comment: you don't need a pointer here

Comment: `str_ptr` points to *a copy* of `vec[0]`

Comment: Please if you push back a single character then show it as a single character, and add comments or text in the question-body about what you expect to happen and what actually happens (for example by showing expected and actual output). Also please take some time to learn how to create a [mcve] that we could copy-paste and try for ourselves without needing big edits or changes, and also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In all fairness it compiles, at least on gcc, if you don't turn warnings into errors.

Comment: @NathanCooper Does it? Can you provide a demonstration? That would be most peculiar, since `push_back` has no overload taking no arguments.

Comment: Copy to https://godbolt.org/ and pick pretty an up-to-date clang or gcc

Comment: Please explain, what you are trying to do. For me it's unclear whats the code supposed to do.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica The code in the question has an argument.

Comment: @vll The only statement anywhere about the code not compiling refers to `str_ptr->push_back()` (which I can only imagine came from a previous revision in the post's grace period).

Comment: @NathanCooper The _current_ code compiles; nobody claimed otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make_shared` does not mean "make this already-existing thing be shared".

It means "make a new shared thing with the following constructor arguments".

You're dynamically allocating a new string that copies `vec[0]` (i.e. using the copy constructor).

If you want `vec[0]` to be a `shared_ptr<string>`, then you need to make it one from the start.

Comment: Solution: `auto * const str_ptr = &vec[0]` or `auto& str_ref = vec[0]`.

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: @Ayxan That depends on the requirements. The OP has already shown they know how to get a basic pointer/reference alias out of the language. Presumably there's more to it, when it comes to their attempt to use shared_ptr here.